# Protocol for Converting External Unnormalized Data to Normalized Tables

Tags: database-design, normalization, import

I'm working through the fundamentals of bringing data from Excel (or any single unnormalized form table model) to SQL (MySQL or SQLite).

These are the steps I've extrapolated from reading:

1. Import data to a single table
2. Assign Headers
3. Match Columns Into Tables
4. Duplicate Table-Seperated Columns to New Table
5. Remove Duplicate Rows from New Tables
6. Reset Auto-Increment
7. Attach Foreign Keys to Original Table by matching column data on New Tables
8. Remove Columns on Old Table represented by Foreign Keys/New Table
9. Repeat 4-8 for each new table until DB is normalized

Is this a rational flow?